# Null object reference while using a Retrofit service on Android 9 (Pie)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2, android-xml

I am fetching movie details from ***"https://api.themoviedb.org/"*** using retrofit. The app works fine on android 5 (Lolipop) but the app crashes on Android 9. Did my research and came to know about the fact that Android pie uses only HTTPS by default. You can clearly see the above URL is encrypted, so, it shouldn't be an issue. Still, I created a *Network Security Configuration* file and included it inside my *AndroidManifest.xml*

And its still not working!!

I am sharing the code below ->

MovieClient.java

```
public class MovieClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/";

    private Retrofit trendingMovieClient;

    //Function for creating a client to receive movie data
    public Retrofit getTrendingMovieClient(){
        if(trendingMovieClient == null) {
            trendingMovieClient = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return trendingMovieClient;
    }
}
```

MovieService.java

```
    public interface MovieService {

    @GET("3/trending/all/day")
    Call<MovieJsonData> getTrendingMovies(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);

    @GET("3/discover/movie")
    Call<MovieJsonData> getMostPopularMovies(@Query("api_key") String apiKey,
                                             @Query("language") String language,
                                             @Query("sort_by") String sortBy,
                                             @Query("page") String page);

    @GET("3/discover/movie")
    Call<MovieJsonData> getTopRatedMovies(@Query("api_key") String apiKey,
                                          @Query("language") String language,
                                          @Query("sort_by") String sortBy,
                                          @Query("page") String page,
                                          @Query("vote_count.gte") String voteCountGte,
                                          @Query("vote_count.lte") String voteCountLte,
                                          @Query("vote_average.gte") String voteAverageGte);

    @GET("3/movie/{movie_id}")
    Call<MovieDetailsJson> getMovieDetails(@Path("movie_id") String movieId,
                                           @Query("api_key") String apiKey,
                                           @Query("language") String language);
}
```

MoviePresenter.java

```
    public class MoviePresenter implements TrendingModule.Presenter{
    private TrendingModule.View moduleView;
    private MovieAdapter.ClickListener listener;
    private MovieAdapter adapter;

    private static final String API_KEY = "";
    private String sort_key;

    private static final String trending = "trending";
    private static final String most_popular = "most_popular";
    private static final String top_rated = "top_rated";

    //POPULAR MOVIES
    private static final String LANGUAGE_MOST_POPULAR = "en-US";
    private static final String SORT_MOST_POPULAR = "popularity.desc";
    private static final String PAGE_MOST_POPULAR = "1";

    //TOP RATED MOVIES
    private static final String LANGUAGE_TOP_RATED = "en-US";
    private static final String SORT_TOP_RATED = "popularity.desc";
    private static final String PAGE_TOP_RATED = "1";
    private static final String VOTE_COUNT_GTE = "100";
    private static final String VOTE_COUNT_LTE = "1500";
    private static final String VOTE_AVERAGE_GTE = "8";

    public MoviePresenter(TrendingModule.View view, MovieAdapter.ClickListener listener, String key){
        this.moduleView = view;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.sort_key = key;
        moduleView.initView();
        initPresenter();
    }

    @Override
    public void initPresenter() {
        fetchData();
    }

    @Override
    public void fetchData() {
        moduleView.progressBarVisible();

        MovieClient movieClient = new MovieClient();
        Retrofit networkClient = movieClient.getTrendingMovieClient();

        //Starting a service to fetch JSON data
        MovieService trendingService = networkClient.create(MovieService.class);

        Call<MovieJsonData> movieData = null;

        //Fetching results through the service
        if(sort_key == null || sort_key.equals(trending)) {
            movieData = trendingService.getTrendingMovies(API_KEY);
        }
        else{
            if(sort_key.equals(most_popular)){
                movieData = trendingService.
                        getMostPopularMovies(
                                API_KEY,
                                LANGUAGE_MOST_POPULAR,
                                SORT_MOST_POPULAR,
                                PAGE_MOST_POPULAR);
            }
            else if(sort_key.equals(top_rated)){
                movieData = trendingService.
                        getTopRatedMovies(
                                API_KEY,
                                LANGUAGE_TOP_RATED,
                                SORT_TOP_RATED,
                                PAGE_TOP_RATED,
                                VOTE_COUNT_GTE,
                                VOTE_COUNT_LTE,
                                VOTE_AVERAGE_GTE);
            }
            else{
                moduleView.noResponse();
            }
        }
            movieData.enqueue(new Callback<MovieJsonData>() {
            @Override @EverythingIsNonNull
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieJsonData> call, Response<MovieJsonData> response) {
                moduleView.recyclerViewVisible();
                MovieJsonData movieJsonData = response.body();
                adapter = new MovieAdapter(movieJsonData, listener);

                moduleView.displayMovieData(adapter);
            }

            @Override @EverythingIsNonNull
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieJsonData> call, Throwable t) {
                moduleView.noResponse();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

network_security_config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <domain-config
        cleartextTrafficPermitted = "true">
        <domain includeSubdomains = "true">themoviedb.org</domain>
    </domain-config>

</network-security-config>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.moviesapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
        <activity
            android:name=".view.Settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".view.TrendingMovies" />
        <activity android:name=".view.MovieDetail"
            android:parentActivityName=".view.TrendingMovies"/>
        <activity android:name=".view.TrendingMovies"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error ->

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void retrofit2.Call.enqueue(retrofit2.Callback)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.moviesapp.presenter.MoviePresenter.fetchData(MoviePresenter.java:107)
```

Comment: The exception seems to point at the fact that `movieData` is not initialized. The only way I see this can happen is if you fall into the else branch where you do `moduleView.noResponse();`. At this point `movieData` is definitely null and you're going to call `enqueue` on it causing the above exception. I suppose you should try and figure out what's the difference with `sort_key` between android versions, since that's what the `if` statements use. I don't think this is a problem with retrofit.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I will look into it!

Comment: By the way, I am kind of a beginner and was trying to implement MVP. Do you see any other flaws in the way I wrote my code??

Comment: Not really flaws. I maybe would have written the presenter a bit differently. I'd have the view call `fetchData` and pass in the sort key. The reason is simply because it let's you reuse the same presenter for different "sorts" which could be useful if you want to allow the  user to choose the sorting.

Comment: You are right!! Calling "fetchData" from the view sounds better. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed when I initialized movieData with a default non-null value:

```
Call<MovieJsonData> movieData = null;
```

changed to ->

```
Call<MovieJsonData> movieData = trendingService.getTrendingMovies(API_KEY);
```